# CSS table display not filling table

Tags: css, css-tables

I have [this](http://jsbin.com/favera/6/edit?html,css,output) jsbin using CSS table display properties. I would expect the rows to fill the whole width of the `display: table` container, and the cells to fill the rows, but instead, the rows seem to be auto-sized to their content. Can anyone figure out what's going on?

Comment: You can try to set the elements (tr/td) width:100%. Rgds,

Comment: Doesn't do anything. Has no effect on the tr, and only makes the content fill the (too small) tr when done on the td.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need the `table` `table-row` `table-cell` format?

As far as I tested, `table-row` doesn't respond to widths. When the `tr` is removed and used as a normal element, the whole thing works again.

[edited bin](http://jsbin.com/korijevesu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: That's as may be, but that doesn't help if you want multiple rows; for example, let's say I wanted a bunch of inputs on top of each other, each with a label beside it. Without the table-rows, it would just be one long row of elements.

Comment: You can use vertical List instead of Table. Rgds,

Comment: @AlexBell That wouldn't allow me to keep the labels and inputs aligned with each other. That is, each label and input would take its own width, regardless of the other labels and inputs. I could set an explicit width on them, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: Then you can use just a regular table element, like it's done, for example in this web layout (btw, it also has fixed header): http://webinfocentral.com/DigiCam.aspx#nav.

Comment: Yes, I could, but it's not actually tabular data; using a table element isn't semantically correct in this case.